# Why the results of comparing two string missed the last matched string?

Tags: c++, string, csv, compare, getline

I comparing two strings in a csv file. 
Since the result of parsing csv file is getting rows of data separated by commas.

The coding works fine but it cannot display the last matched line.

CSV file content:

```
Title,sn,sn,sn
test,123,344,222
test,123,344,222
test,123,344,222
test,123,344,222
test,456,677,223
test,5,4545,32
apple,23,44,22
apple,323,23,22
```

eg, my codes just displayed the content below which missing the last matched line,

```
Title,sn,sn,sn
test,123,344,222
test,123,344,222
test,123,344,222
test,123,344,222
test,456,677,223
```

instead of,

```
Title,sn,sn,sn
test,123,344,222
test,123,344,222
test,123,344,222
test,123,344,222
test,456,677,223
test,5,4545,32
```

codes as below:

```
int main()
{
    string line;
    ifstream file("sample.csv");

    if(!file)
    {
        cout << "Error, could not open file." << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    while(getline(file, line))
    {
        stringstream ss(line);
        string line2;

        getline(file, line2, ',');

        string str = "test";
        if(line2 == str)
        {
            cout << line << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every loop, you get a line, and the line after it. When the loop gets to the last line, it doesn't have a line after it, so the comparison with "test" is never true since you're already looking at the last line. If you change the second getline to `getline(ss, line2, ',');`, now you're only looking at a single line through each loop since you're pulling the first part of each line from ss instead of the file (But the first line with `Title,sn,sn,sn` is skipped.) To skip checking the first line (if that line is a title) you can put an additional `getline(file, line);` before the loop.

Comment: Thank you so much, @10101 =)